# The difference between setting a new state and changing the old state using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to set the value of one of the keys of the state in my component. The state looks like that:

```
this.state = {
        stateValue1: false,
        stateValue2: false,
        stateValue3: false
    };
```

To change my state I use the function:

```
 handleSwitch = type => {

    this.setState((prevState, type) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [type]: !prevState[type]
    }));

};
```

Depending on which key of the state I would like to change I use it like:

```
handleSwitch("stateValue2")
```

But as the result I get

```
    {
        stateValue1: false,
        stateValue2: false,
        stateValue3: false
        [object Object]: true
    }
```

However, when I am using the new object as an argument of `setState` function everything works fine. Why?

Working code:

```
handleNotificationSwitch = type => {
    const newState = {
        ...this.state,
        [type]: !this.state[type]
    };

    this.setState(newState);
};
```

And its result:

```
    {
        stateValue1: false,
        stateValue2: true,
        stateValue3: false
    }
```

Comment: `(prevState, type) =>`, shadowing the `type` parameter in the containing function? The second argument given to the updater is `props`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove or rename the second argument from the function you pass to `setState`.

```
this.setState( prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    [type]: !prevState[type]
}));
```

or

```
this.setState( ( prevState, props ) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [type]: !prevState[type]
}));
```

The `type` argument passed to `handleSwitch` is the value you want - inside `setState`, `type` is set to whatever React passes to that function, which is `props`.

Answer (score 3):

According to [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) an updater function of `setState` accept two params, second is `props`. So, actually, you're setting `props` to state.

Comment: `props` is the second `param` of the `updater` `function`.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to the updater function is the components current props, an object. [React setState Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

I suspect you want something more like the following, assuming `type` is a prop:

```
handleSwitch = type => {

    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [props.type]: !prevState[props.type]
    }));

};
```

Or, you were intending to use the `type` parameter passed to `handleSwitch`, in which case:

```
handleSwitch = type => {

    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [type]: !prevState[type]
    }));

};
```